# angularjs $resource Consuming domainservice error[Error: [ng:areq]] xxxx

Tags: angularjs

**Does anyone know how you can check to see that a resource failed to be fetched in AngularJS?

error:

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ng/areq?p0=PhotoListCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

**

```
<html ng-app>
        <head>
            <title>angularjs</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="PhotoListCtrl">
            <h1>Angular js</h1>
            <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>
            <button title="list" ng-click="list()">list</button>
            <button title="copy" ng-click="copy()" >copy</button>
            <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
                    <img src="{{'data:image/png;base64,' + photo.Image}}" title="{{photo.Name}}"></img>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-resource.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              var app=  angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']).factory('dataservice', function ($resource) {
                    return $resource('/applicationdata.svc/Photos/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
                        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
                        get: { method: 'GET', params: {id:0} },
                        remove: { method: 'DELETE' },
                        edit: { method: 'PUT' },
                        add: { method: 'POST' }
                    });
                });

                app.controller('PhotoListCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataservice', function ($scope, dataservice) {
                    $scope.photos = [];
                    $scope.list = function () {
                        dataservice.query({}, function (data) {
                            $scope.photos = data.value;
                        });
                    };

                }]);


                //function PhotoListCtrl($scope ,$http) {
                //    $http.get('/applicationdata.svc/Photos').success(function (data) {
                //        $scope.photos = data.value;

                //    });


                //    $scope.orderProp = 'Name';

                //    $scope.copy = function () {
                //        $http.post('/applicationdata.svc/Photos', $scope.photos[0]).success(function (data) {
                //            console.log(data);

                //        });
                //    }

                //}



            </script>


        </body>
        </html>
```